# CellFormating get curent row

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, cell-formatting

I am using DataGridView CellFormating to format specified cells.
The code I am trying:

```
 private void dgwPart_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.arts.Type == ArtType.Pak)
        {
            if (dgwPart.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Discount")
                e.Value = "";
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it changes the value for all column, but I only want that it changes the value for specified row. How do I manage it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.CurrentCell to find whether it is the row you want, something like:

```
    If (dvImages.CurrentCell.RowIndex == 10)
    { 
        Debug.WriteLine("Do something")
    }

    If ((int)(dvImages.CurrentCell.Value) = 100)
    {
       ...
    }
```

*** these should be within the cellformat, after you check the column. 
you may need check the syntax, I just typed this from my header.